# time out errors on sql server 2003

Tags: sql-server

we are having ongoing time out issues/conenction issues with our Sql server db 2003. some people think if we add three more drives (up from 5 now) this will spread the load and cut down on these time out issues. What do you think?

this was the advice (below) does this make sense?

1. Add at least three more disk volume 
   e.g. 
   Log File: F drive
   Tempdb: G Drive
   Backup Drive or external storage: K ( Full/Differential Database Backup, Transaction backup)

   2. Move tempdb database on G drive
   3. Move log file of database like Enterprise and ssdn on F drive.
   4. Logs database are in FULL recovery model. if this is only for audit and only have insert operation, i would suggest to change it to Simple recovery model.
   5. DO NOT TAKE BACKUP IN data or log file drive. (Currently transaction log backup happening in E Drive which is data and log file location)
   6. Configured user options e.g. “Set Nocount on” at Server Level as user didn’t use as best practice.

Comment: You've been given advice to add more memory and to reconfigure your disk subsystem and to make changes to the SQL Server configuration. If I were you at this point I'd bring in a SQL Server expert to analyze your performance issues and recommend a solution based on real performance data and analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the joeqwerty - you need an expert; the wording & answers just don't sound like there has been a solid review done.  These changes could be useful if somebody has done a good job profiling the server and can backup the need for these choices with solid monitoring data.  Otherwise you're just throwing darts.  #3. is particularly troublesome;  there are reasons to have full recovery other than audit (like disaster recovery, log shipping).